# Cat5e - No link after keystone install

Tags: networking, router, ethernet, cable

I have a cat5e cable ran, from my router on my second floor, through the wall up into my finished attic.  I initially had it terminated on both ends with RJ45 plugs, and my gaming console connected to my router perfectly fine.

While rearranging some furniture a week ago, I decided to clean up my cable install with a keystone jack in the attic, instead of having the cable running out of the wall plate.  Since installing the keystone, I no longer have connection to my router.  This has been tested with multiple devices with the same result; no connection.  Both ends of the cat5e cable (rj45 going to the router, and the keystone jack) are wired 568A.

I'm puzzled because it worked perfectly fine before.  The only change I have made was to cut the cat5e down to a reasonable length (since I didn't need 10 ft spooled up behind the wall plate), and having wired a keystone jack into the wall.  Should also be noted that I have tried two different keystones, as well as a new rj45 plug at the router and in the attic, AFTER cutting it down.

I'm thinking I'm likely going to have to re-run a new cable between the two rooms, but I'd rather exhaust all other possibilities before doing that.  Posting here because I'm just wondering if there is anything I might be overlooking.  Thanks

Comment: Do you have a continuity tester? And what did you use to punch the cable to the jack?

Comment: Although it is likely a crimping error, it should be noted that (in an ideal world) sockets are connected using single core, while leads use stranded core - so the cable you are using is probably incorrect - it should work, but its not going to be as performant.

Comment: @davidgo you mean stranded vs solid core right? Stranded also makes a real mess out of these Jack's terminating points when you have to re-terminate.

Comment: Yes, stranded vs solid core. (You do know not to strip  the plastic round the inner wires I hope.)

Comment: I do not have a continuity tester, unfortunately.  Any recommendations on one to get?  Also, I used the plastic punch down tool that came with the jack to punch the cable.

Yes, I know not to strip the plastic from the inner wires.  I did not know, however, that there are two different types of cable (stranded/solid).  If I do end up having to re-run the line, you'd recommend that I use stranded core instead?